# How do you use JSON.dump() to output a newline without a backslash?

Tags: python-3.x

In python3,

```
>>> json.dumps('\n\x0a', ensure_ascii=False)

'"\\n\\n"'
```

The output has 6 characters. Why is it not '"\n\n"'? Is it possible to not add the overhead (ensure_ascii=False)?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, this seems to get rid of those backslashes:

```
>>> json.dumps('\n\x0a').encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
'"\n\n"'
```

Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings

Answer (score 0):

@navneethc has already shown how to remove the extra backslashes, and unfortunately I can't comment at the moment as I don't have enough reputation.

But I wanted to answer your question

> Why is it not '"\n\n"'?

I believe an extra backslash has been added to prevent the python interpreter from reading the string as a literal new-line character.

Answer (score 0):

> The output has 6 characters. Why is it not '"\n\n"'?

Because then it would **not** be a valid JSON. See: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Of course, if you really need, you can obtain a **non-standard** *quasi-JSON* string, e.g., with all characters *unescaped* except `"` and `\` (which are crucial to keep string literals parsable in any sensible way):

```
>>> import json
>>> def show(obj):  # (a small helper)
...     print(ascii(obj))
... 
>>> # space-separated: NULL, LINEFEED, 0x1F, `"`, `\`, `↑`-arrow, ``-emoji, lone surrogate
>>> difficult_to_handle = '\0 \n \x1f " \\ \u2191 \U0001f64f \udcdd'
>>> show(difficult_to_handle)
'\x00 \n \x1f " \\ \u2191 \U0001f64f \udcdd'

>>> # to be able after json.dumps() to apply a fast '\'-unescapeing
>>> # without making the string literals completely unparsable
>>> # we need to "pre-escape" all '\' and '"' characters in
>>> # any strings our data include, *before* json.dumps():
>>> pre_escaped = difficult_to_handle.translate({34: '\\"', 92: '\\\\'})
>>> show(pre_escaped)
'\x00 \n \x1f \\" \\\\ \u2191 \U0001f64f \udcdd'

>>> json_ascii_pre_escaped = json.dumps(pre_escaped)
>>> show(json_ascii_pre_escaped)
'"\\u0000 \\n \\u001f \\\\\\" \\\\\\\\ \\u2191 \\ud83d\\ude4f \\udcdd"'

>>> # unescape all \-escaped stuff:
>>> quasi_json_with_surrogates = (json_ascii_pre_escaped
...                               .encode('ascii')
...                               .decode('unicode_escape'))
>>> show(quasi_json_with_surrogates)
'"\x00 \n \x1f \\" \\\\ \u2191 \ud83d\ude4f \udcdd"'

>>> # convert surrogate pairs to proper code
>>> # points, but keep lone surrogates intact:
>>> quasi_json = (quasi_json_with_surrogates
...               .encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')
...               .decode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass'))
>>> show(quasi_json)
'"\x00 \n \x1f \\" \\\\ \u2191 \U0001f64f \udcdd"'
```